# Как заинъектить Mock объект в Мock объект?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, mocking

У меня получается есть сервис слой, и есть ДАО слой, как за мокировать дао слой, который в свою очередь  я хочу заинъектить в сервис слой, который также будет замокирован?

---

Я вот не понимаю. У меня есть вот такой код в тесте.

```
@Mock
private NewsService mockNewsService;

@Mock
private CommentService mockCommentService;

@Mock
private TagService mockTagService;

@Mock
private AuthorService mockAuthorService;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private TransactionManagement transactionManagement;
```

и для всего определены соответсвующие бины в xml.
Я не понимаю тогда почему отрабатывает ДАО?
Получается что мой Сервис как МОК не работает, а пускает дальше сервиса, уже в дао, почему может быть так?
У меня в итоге выдает в дао слое ошибку, что я передаю туда значение нулл.
Получается если замокировать только сервис этого не достаточно?
нужно и дао. 
так как у меня сервис вызывает дао слой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим есть класс MyService:

```
public class MyService {
    @Inject
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    //остальной код

}
```

То в тесте можно MyDAO заинъектить так:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private MyDAO mockDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService service;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

}
```

Если сам MyService мок, то смысла и возможности нет иньектить туда MyDAO.

Comment: Да, если я не сделаем моком наш ДАО в тесте, то он будет работать как реальный объект. Мне нет смысла в этом, получается я не могу ему задать определенное поведение, и мне приходится передавать туда реальный объект. 
Получается Сервис работает как Mock но ДАО нет.

Comment: У меня задача такая. Сделать Моком ДАО.
Сделать моком Сервис.
Заинъектить туда дао, а мой сервис в свою очередь инъектиться в класс МэнэджераТранзакций. и так я дергаю мой МокСервис, но при этом у меня ДАО слой работае как реальный объект, мне так не нужно.

Comment: Я просто хочу знать как с помощью аннотаций можно сделать Мок в Моке.
У меня есть interface XDAO {

Comment: Я просто хочу знать как с помощью аннотаций можно сделать Мок в Моке.
У меня есть: interface XDAO { ... } 
Я его имплиментирую: class XDAOImpl implements XDAO{ ... }
Также у меня есть сервис интерфейс.
interface XService { ... }
Я также его имплиментирую, а в имплиментации я Inject туда мое ДАО.
class XServiceImpl {
private XDAO xDAO; 
public void setXDAO(XDAO xDAO) {
this.xDAO=xDAO; 
}

Comment: Если есть мок XService xservice = mock(XService.class); то туда ничего не возможно заиньектить, т.к. это мок, а не ваш какой-то класс. Но можно отдельно создать мок для дао: XDAO xdao =  mock(XDAO.class); И потом написать: when(xservice.getXDAO()).thenReturn(xdao);

Comment: Я вот не понимаю, посмотрите пожалуйста другой мой комментарий.!

Comment: Я не знаю, может это как нибудь связанно с тем, что я тестирую класс, который в котором методы транзации, в их конфигурирую как транзакции в xml файлу, с помощью Spring AOP.